# How to modify the SQL data of a row selected in a dropdown menu?

Tags: php, sql, text, input, types

I'm beginning in PHP and I've been tasked to create a form with which the user can select a category (a row from a table in the MySQL Database) and update the content of a specific column in that row.

[**Here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnsW8.png) is what it looks like. [**Here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4Dwh.png) is what the table in MySQL looks like (tva is the column in which I want to update the content)

Here is what the code looks like :

```html
<tr>
  <td>Modify the TVA of :  </td>
  <td>
    <select name="tva_modif">
    <?
    $sql_tva_modif = "SELECT id_type, nom_fr,tva
          FROM type
          ORDER BY nom_fr
            ;";
    $sql_tva_modif_result = mysql_query($sql_tva_modif);
    while($val_tva_modif = mysql_fetch_array($sql_tva_modif_result))
    {
     echo "<option value='" . $val_tva_modif["id_type"] . "'>" . $val_tva_modif["nom_fr"] . "</option>";
    }
    ?>
  </select>
  <input name="tva_val" id="tva_val" type="text" value=""></div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

If possible, can someone explain me how to make sure that the input type text field display the TVA value of the selected option and how to make that field update the content of that column in my database ?

Comment: The field showed in the table & the name u r using here r different ie id_categorie is not there in table at all.

Comment: Yes, sorry I mistyped it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using id_categorie field which is not mention in select query

```
<?php
    $sql_tva_modif = "SELECT id_type, nom_fr,tva
              FROM type
              ORDER BY nom_fr
               ;";
    $sql_tva_modif_result = mysql_query($sql_tva_modif);
?>

<tr>
  <td>Modify the TVA of :  </td>
  <td>
    <select name="tva_modif" id="tva_modif">
    <?php
      while($val_tva_modif = mysql_fetch_array($sql_tva_modif_result))
      {
        echo "<option value='" . $val_tva_modif["id_type"] . "' id='" . $val_tva_modif["tva"] . "' >" . $val_tva_modif["nom_fr"] . "</option>";
      }
    ?>
  </select>
  <input name="tva_val" id="tva_val" type="text" value=""></div>
  </td>
</tr>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#tva_modif').change(function()
    {
        var id = $(this).children(":selected").attr("id");
        if(id != ""){
            $('#tva_val').val(id);
        }
        else
        {
          $('#tva_val').val('');
        }
    });

    </script>
```

Comment: Yes indeed, sorry for that, I gave it the wrong field name

Comment: Thank you, I'm almost there. There is only a little problem, the input type text field displays the "id_type" value instead of "tva". Is there a way to change this ?

Comment: How about the first value when the page loads freshly?

Comment: Now that you're talking about it, it doesn't load if you don't first choose another type

Comment: I am talking about the code improvement its not an argument. Hope you get it.

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
      var id = $('#tva_modif').children(":selected").attr("id");
      $('#tva_val').val(id);
    });

Comment: Thanks again it's perfect !

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this

```
  <tr>
      <td>Modify the TVA of :  </td>
      <td>
        <select name="tva_modif" id="ss1">
        <?
        $sql_tva_modif = "SELECT id_type, nom_fr,tva
                          FROM type
                          ORDER BY nom_fr
                         ;";
        $sql_tva_modif_result = mysql_query($sql_tva_modif);
        while($val_tva_modif = mysql_fetch_array($sql_tva_modif_result))
        {
            echo "<option value='" . $val_tva_modif["id_categorie"] . "'>" . $val_tva_modif["nom_fr"] . "</option>";
        }
        ?>
      </select>
      <input name="tva_val" id="tva_val" type="text" value=""></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
   $('#ss1').change(function(){
    var selected_item = $(this).val()

    if(selected_item ){
    $('#tva_val').val(selected_item).addClass('hidden');
       // $('#tva_val').val("").removeClass('hidden');
    }else{
        $('#tva_val').val("").removeClass('hidden');
    }
});
    </script>
```

Please check this link [JSDEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/mjshanukk/x6g8s3qs/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I tried this but it made the input type text field disappear.

Comment: @Lightsplasher: Please refere that link its working for me

Comment: It's not a problem anymore I got it working. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

To update the content of your input you have to add a bit of Javascript (I advise you to add an ID to your `<select>` such as "vat_select"),

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("vat_select").onchange = function(){
        document.getElementById("tva_val").value = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
    }
</script>
```

Be careful, I believe you have an error in your SELECT, you need to select the `"id_categorie"` too, otherwise your option values will be empty.

To update data in your table (whichever it is) I advise you to take a look at [this](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp).
You should modify your instructions starting with "mysql" by "mysqli" (while having mysqli activated in PHP), because they are deprecated.

PS : VAT is the English for TVA.

Comment: I am not getting y do we need javascript here, the data needs to be put in database ryt? we can do that by using ajax or the other is direct php call on form submission ryt?

Comment: You asked for it "can someone explain me how to make sure that the input type text field display the TVA value of the selected option"

Comment: Yes of course we need js or jquery. but when i asked you i just thought of update and not of selection combo box & text field mapping just a confusion in question. And again my question was to clarify what exactly needed and not to argue.

Comment: I wasn't arguing, I was merely pointing you towards what you asked, no worries man ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need:

```
    <?php 
if(isset($_POST["submit_tva"])){
    $id_type_and_tva_array = explode("_", $_POST["tva_modif"]);
    $sql_query = "UPDATE table_name SET tva='".$_POST["tva_val"]."' WHERE id_type='".$id_type_and_tva_array[0]."'";
    mysql_query($sql_query);
}
?>

<form method="post">
 <table>
<tr>
  <td>Modify the TVA of :  </td>
  <td>
    <select name="tva_modif" id="tva_modif">
    <?
    $sql_tva_modif = "SELECT id_type, nom_fr,tva
                      FROM type
                      ORDER BY nom_fr
                     ;";
    $sql_tva_modif_result = mysql_query($sql_tva_modif);
    while($val_tva_modif = mysql_fetch_array($sql_tva_modif_result))
    {
        echo "<option value='" . $val_tva_modif["id_type"] . "_".$val_tva_modif["tva"]."'>" . $val_tva_modif["nom_fr"] . "</option>";
    }
    $val_tva_modif = mysql_fetch_array($sql_tva_modif_result)
    ?>
  </select>
  <input name="tva_val" id="tva_val" type="text" value="<?php echo $val_tva_modif["tva"]; ?>"></div>
  </td>
  <td><input type="submit" name="submit_tva" type="text" value="Update"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#tva_modif').change(function()
    {
     var id_type_and_tva = $("tva_modif").val();
     var id_type_and_tva_array = id_type_and_tva.split("_");
     var tva = id_type_and_tva_array[1];
     $("#tva_val").val(tva);
    });

    </script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help ! Is there a way to display the corresponding tva value of the selected option ? I need it to be visible for users

Comment: Check the answer now